# android - socket timeout while connecting

Tags: android, sockets

I'm trying to implement a tcp client app on Android. When I try to connect to my C++ server, the socket times out while trying to connect to the server.

My code:

```
new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
try
{
  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
  out.println("Test message.");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  // ERROR1
  e.printStackTrace();
}

...

class ClientThread implements Runnable
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    try
    {
      InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.116");
      socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 9000);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      // ERROR2
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

First, the ERROR1 occurs (socket is null), then the ERROR2 occurs (connection time out). The server is working fine, I have tested it with different clients. I have "uses-permission" so it shouldn't be a problem.

EDIT:
stack at ERROR2:

```
05-17 02:26:50.789: W/System.err(26625): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.116 (port 9000): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
05-17 02:26:50.789: W/System.err(26625):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
05-17 02:26:50.789: W/System.err(26625):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
05-17 02:26:50.789: W/System.err(26625):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
05-17 02:26:50.789: W/System.err(26625):    at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
05-17 02:26:50.789: W/System.err(26625):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:225)
05-17 02:26:50.789: W/System.err(26625):    at cz.gclient.gardenclient.MainActivity$ClientThread.run(MainActivity.java:153)
05-17 02:26:50.789: W/System.err(26625):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-17 02:26:50.789: W/System.err(26625): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
05-17 02:26:50.789: W/System.err(26625):    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
05-17 02:26:50.789: W/System.err(26625):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
05-17 02:26:50.789: W/System.err(26625):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
05-17 02:26:50.789: W/System.err(26625):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
05-17 02:26:50.789: W/System.err(26625):    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Well suppose you fix the NPE, which is caused by doing operations in the wrong order, and post the exception & stack trace in your question so can see what you're talking about.

Comment: the order is right, the socket thing has to be in its own thread... i will add stack print to original post

Comment: No, the order isn't right. You're creating the PrintWriter before you've created the socket on which it depends. Why do you think you're getting the NPE exactly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

'Connection time out' is a network connectivity problem. There may be a firewall in the way for example. It isn't a programming problem and you can't solve it in code.

Comment: I was connected to another network with my tablet... I'm so stupid :D Thanks :)